# Spring Security Logout Redirect not including GET parameters

Tags: spring, spring-security

I've got a spring security 3.2.5.RELEASE app running and have the following configurations:

```
<intercept-url pattern="/Login.html*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
```

And, within the same `<http>` tag...

```
<logout invalidate-session="true" 
             logout-success-url="/Login.html?msg=logout" 
             delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" />
```

Other endpoints in the `<http`> element require the user to be authenticated, and `invalid-session-url="/Login.html"`

Upon logging out, my browser appears to be redirected to `Login.html?msg=logout`, and then redirected again to `Login.html`.

[image: Chrome debug window.]

This makes me think that the `/Login.html*` is not matching correctly, and I'm not sure how to change the intercept-url to allow matching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like a recent upgrade to Spring Security 3.2.5.RELEASE has changed the way our app handled invalid sessions. The `access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"` now still seems to check for invalid sessions or not, and when redirected to the url `Login.html?msg=logout`, the sessionId was still being interpreted on the server. Since it was no longer a valid sessionId, the client was then redirected to the `invalid-session-url`.

The solution for me was to put the Login.html page in its own `<http>` tag, with `security="none"`.

The new Login element looks like this:

`<http pattern="/Login.**" security="none"/>`

Note: I also needed to put the public assets path in its own `<http security="none">` tag so that the Login page could access them.